# In javascript should I use const instead of var whenever possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants, var, ecmascript-6

If creating a reference to an object, and the reference is not going to change (even though the object will), is it better to use const instead of var?

For example:

```
const moment = require('moment')

exports.getQuotation = function(value) {

    const quotation = {};
    quotation.value = value;
    quotation.expiryDate = moment().add(7, 'days');

    // Do some other stuff with quotation perhaps

    return quotation;

};
```

Comment: I would not mess with const, is ES6, it will not increment your code performance but it will make a bit more difficult to fix and refactor. Stick with var (always declare you variables)

Comment: @donnanicolas ES6 `const`and `let` are pretty much final

Answer (score 4):

You can use const, but you have to run node on `--harmony`

```
node app.js --harmony
```

You also have to set `"use strict"`, otherwise you'll have run-time execution issues:

```
exports.getQuotation = function(value) {
    "use strict";

    const I_AM_CONSTANT = {};
    let quotation = {};
    ...
```

Other than that, yes if you are running node on `--harmony`, semantically it makes more sense to use `const` for constants. For actual variables you should use `let` instead of var, as `let` only defines the variable in the scope (avoids hoisting issues)

Answer (score 3):

If you check MDN, for its reference you can find that its an experimental technology which is part of ES6 proposal. Its browser support is limited.

Reference for [**const**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) from MDN

> This is an experimental technology, part of the Harmony (ECMAScript 6)
>   proposal. Because this technology's specification has not stabilized,
>   check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note
>   that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject
>   to change in future version of browsers as the spec changes.

So this answers whether you should use everywhere. :)

Also if you want to create properties in objects which should not be allowed to change, then you should check [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) and the  use of `writable` attribute.

Comment: I don't think this is what the requestor meant. I think the question is "If I'm in an environment supporting `const` and `let`, which one should I prefer?" He says `var`, but I think the question is more about `let` which has the same block scope.

Comment: @Pipo : I am sorry. I got this from your comment. But where is it in the question?

Comment: I think it is this part "If creating a reference to an object, and the reference is not going to change (even though the object will), is it better to use `const` instead of `foo`?". I changed `var` to `foo` to make it clear that I _think_ he doens't want a real comparison to `var` (or `let`), but looking at the first part, I think he wants to know, if it is generally good to use `const` for Objects, if their contents change.

Answer (score 1):

[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is used for a variable constant, i.e. once declared, it's value is not supposed to change, whereas `var` can be changed as per the will.

Use of `const` and `var` is solely on your will. For me it goes as follows

- If I'm 100% sure that the value of a variable is not going to change and it's not going to re-declared, I'll define it as a const.
- In all other cases I'll use var.

Mind it, re-declaring `const` will immediately throw an error.